# Eliminate element of every list within a nested list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, nested-lists

I would like to eliminate the third element of every list within a nested list.

E.g.,

```
    lst = { {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 4} }
```

So it would become

```
    { {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 1} }
```

How should I do that?

Comment: You could write a loop and create a new nested list with only the values you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Mathematica. That's exactly what I want to understand how to do.

Comment: I'm sure that by now you have read the documentation for `Cases` since I used it in my answer to your previous question.  Return to that documentation and you will find how to use the same function to make replacements for matched patterns.  There are other ways to achieve the same results, in particular study the documentation for `->` (*alias* `Rule`) but do stop trying to learn Mathematica by asking one little question at a time; the program is well documented  and Wolfram provide oodles of tutorials.  So too does the Google-sphere.

Comment: Oh, while I'm here, ignore @VenomFangs' advice.  Under no circumstances should you solve this problem by writing a loop; no Mathematica-ian would either suggest or do that.

Comment: @High Performance Mark, do you know how to make the ListPlot function ignore the third components, without having to manipulate the list in the way I am proposing here? I couldn't find this information anywhere. 

I am a bit confused with Mathematica way of manipulating data, because I was a Matlab user. There I could simply use something like  

        Plot( lst(:,1:2) )

Comment: Actually, plot( lst(1,1:2), lst(2,1:2) ).

Comment: you can simply put the construct inside listplot, eg ListPlot[ #[[1;;2]] &/@ list ]

Comment: @george But in Matlab I'm simply asking to read part of the matrix. Don't your solutions correspond to additional (time-consuming) operations?

Comment: comparing mathematica to other things for raw numerical efficiency of simple tasks is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yet another:

```
lst = #[[1;;2]] & /@ lst
```

or if you want to drop only the third element from possibly longer sublists:

```
lst = Drop[#,{3}]& /@ lst
```

Comment: Why do you say "Drop" is for longer lists?

Comment: if your subsists have 4 elements, drop will give you {#1,#2,#4} which is what is literally asked in the question.  The first sol drops everything after #2.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of way to do that, e.g.

```
lst = {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 4}};

lst = lst[[All, {1, 2}]]
```

> {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}

Or

```
lst = Transpose[Most[Transpose[lst]]]
```

Or, without transposing

```
lst = MapThread[Delete, {lst, Table[3, {Length[lst]}]}]
```